# Setting an environment variable from Node script

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci

I have a CI process that uses a NodeJS script to perform a deployment to AWS. Internally, the scripts can deploy to multiple locations based on some conditions.

Is it possible for the script to expose the final deployment location to the CI environment, so I can use it further in the `environment` part of the CI script for example?

I tried `process.env.SOME_VAR = url` in the NodeJS script, but that didn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd generate the [`dotenv` artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv) in your NodeJS job, and then added another deploy job that depends on the NodeJS job, including the artifacts -- this way you can pass results of one job to another.

```yaml
job1:
  script: node my_script.js > envars.sh
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: envars.sh

job2:
  script: deploy.sh
  needs:
   - job: job1
     optional: false
     artifacts: true
```